# Weird popping artifacts in audacity

Tags: mixing, audacity

When I record two separate tracks, they have a little weird anchor looking symbol that I cannot remove no matter what point in the audio I delete it. It "pops" at that point. When I pan the tracks in opposite directions (i.e., 50% left and 50% right) I get the following image in audacity:

[image: audacity]

This creates weird static noise if the gain is too high. Does anybody know why this happens?

Comment: Can you post samples of the audio as well?  I don't hear pictures of waveforms too well. :)

Comment: Besides that, this looks like DC offset combined with phase issues. If you don't use 'snap to zero' this it what will happen when simply chopping up audio..